# Adding a Node in the third level in a TreeView in C#

Tags: c#, exception, treeview

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll.

This is my line of code:

```
View.Nodes[View.Nodes.IndexOf(Node)].Nodes[View.Nodes.IndexOf(Node2)].Nodes.Add(Title3);
```

"View" is a TreeView.

I wonder how to add a node in the third level.

Comment: The exception is self-explanatory, one of your indexes you are trying to access is out of range (more than number of child nodes)

Comment: how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I will extend my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View.Nodes[View.Nodes.IndexOf(Node)].Nodes[View.Nodes.IndexOf(Node2)].Nodes.Add(Title3);
```

`View.Nodes.IndexOf(Node)` is the index of a node in the first level.
You are indexing all levels with an index determined from the first level.
I'm not sure if this is what you wanted. Maybe try this:

```
var firstLevelNodes = View.Nodes;
var secondLevelNodes = firstLevelNodes[firstLevelNodes.IndexOf(nodeInFirst)].Nodes;
var thirdLevelNodes = secondLevelNodes[secondLevelNodes.IndexOf(nodeInSecond)].Nodes;
...
thirdLevelNodes.Add(...);
```

In one line this would be pretty long:)

PS: you can write a function to do this, maybe with a predicate array to select the nodes in each level.

Comment: which type / class type are the Nodes-variables?

Comment: sorry. i mean i don't want to use "var", i want to use something like: TreeNode FirstLevelNodes !

Comment: TreeNodeCollection - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it is like a list, it implements basic IList, ICollection and IEnumerable interfaces.

Comment: something else: how can I go through all depths in a TreeView with ONE function ? thank you !

Comment: if you mean visit each node, you can use recursion. Here's a link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984381(v=vs.71).aspx. If you have some specific question, just make another SO topic.

Comment: i mean iterating through a set of folders and displayin all in a TreeView!